# How to remove "Running" and "Done" information in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Since I'm new to VS Code and I haven't found an answer to it yet, I'm posing the following question:
I installed the Code Runner extension and whenever I'm running my code, I get the output

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/XYZ/ML/main.py"
Hello World

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.101 seconds
```

How can I change this into just outputting

```
Hello World
```

Best.

Answer (score 3):

In the extension [configuration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner&ssr=false#user-content-configuration), set `code-runner.showExecutionMessage` to your liking:

> To set whether to show extra execution message like [Running] ... and [Done] ... (default is `true`):
>
> ```
> {
>     "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Path:**

1. Open VSCode
2. File  (top left navigation bar)
3. Preferences
4. Settings (or as stated by Sage Deshmane (Thanks Sage!), use the shortcut by holding Ctrl and pressing the comma **,** )   This will open up your Settings options in a new tab.
5. Using the search field/input at the top, paste in the keyword "execution message"
6. A single option with a checkbox should be visible.
7. Remove check mark (You don't need to relaunch the application for the setting to take effect)

**Secondary Path:**
If your using an extension like Code Runner (.run)

1. Open your extension from the side bar (shortcut Ctrl + Shift + X)
2. Find code runner and click on the cog wheel to the bottom right
3. Extension Settings
4. Using the search field/input at the top paste the keyword "execution message" to the right of @ext:formulahendry.code-runner execution message.
5. A single option with a checkbox should be visible.
6. Remove check mark (You don't need to relaunch the application for the setting to take effect)

Answer (score -1):

Go to visual studio code , click cntr + , then search for code runner , ther u will find a setting with code runner show execution message. just uncheck that

[refer this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k2bI.png)